# Powershell AD (list empty group and list not used local group)

Tags: powershell

How I can empty local groups?

And How to list local Groups that are not used since a lot of time (more than 30 days for example) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can list empty local groups by calling `Get-LocalGroup` to enumerate all local groups, then use `Get-LocalGroupMember` to test which groups don't have any:

```
$emptyGroups = Get-LocalGroup |Where-Object {-not($_ |Get-LocalGroupMember)}
```

---

> and How to list local Groups that are not used since lot of time (more than 30 days for example) ?

For this, you'll need to [configure, collect and analyze audit events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/audit-policy-recommendations), specifically the `Account Management -> Audit Security Group Management` policy category

Comment: I have an error : 

`code` Get-LocalGroupMember : Failed to compare two elements in the array.
At line:1 char:55
+ ... roups = Get-LocalGroup |Where-Object {-not($_ |Get-LocalGroupMember)}
+                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-LocalGroupMember], Invali 
   dOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : An unspecified error occurred.,Microsoft.PowerSh 
   ell.Commands.GetLocalGroupMemberCommand' `code` `